# Query in vb.net same button only

Tags: mysql, vb.net-2010

im using VB.net 2010 and mysql. I want to execute multiple query at one button only but the second query is not executed. You can see below that it will save at two different tables

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("data source=localhost;database=grade;user id=root;password=sad")
Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
Dim query As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    conn.Open()
    query = "insert into student (studno,name) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
    query2 = "insert into subject (subjcode,subjdesc) values ('" & ComboBox1.Text & "','" & Label5.Text & "')"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()

    conn.Open()
    query = "insert into subject (studno) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()

    conn.Open()
    query = "insert into subject (subjcode,subjdesc) values ('" & ComboBox1.Text & "','" & Label5.Text & "')"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
 End Sub
```

Comment: you have not used query2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query2` not execute because you does not pass the `query2` in command

try like this:

**Create Function :**

```
 Public Sub NonQueryExe(ByVal xCommand as String)

      Dim mysqlas new MySqlCommand(SQCommand, conn)

      conn.open()
      mysqlas.ExecuteNonQuery()
      conn.close()

 End Sub
```

Call that function inside your `button_click`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    NonQueryExe( "insert into student (studno,name) values ('" & 
    TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "')")

    NonQueryExe( "insert into subject (subjcode,subjdesc) 
    values ('" & ComboBox1.Text & "','" & Label5.Text & "')")

    NonQueryExe("insert into subject (studno) 
    values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "')")

    NonQueryExe("insert into subject (subjcode,subjdesc) 
    values ('" & ComboBox1.Text & "','" & Label5.Text & "')")

 End Sub
```